# Gmail is not rendering Font correctly on Emails

Tags: html, css, fonts, gmail, html-email

I've built an html Email and used Google fonts.

I've included the fonts in the head tag using:

```
    ╔!--[if !mso]╗╔!--╗
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:200,300,400,500,600,700" rel="stylesheet"/>
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather+Sans:300,300i,400,400i,700,700i,800,800i" rel="stylesheet"/>
    ╔!--╔![endif]--╗
```

and to use the fonts, i.e I did so:

```
    <tr>
      <td valign="top">
         <p style="line-height:1;margin:0;color:#ffffff;font-family:'Merriweather Sans', sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:normal;">Für Fragen sind wir jederzeit für Dich da:</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

The problem is: the fonts are rendered perfectly on apple mail, on Gmail only Oswald.

I've tried to figure out, why 'Merriweather Sans' is not rendered correctly, but no chance.

Could you help me please?

Comment: if you are working on email templates, its better to use Arial font. Emails does not support other fonts. Else use the font style text as a image in png/jpg format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is: the fonts are rendered perfectly on apple mail, on
>   Gmail only Oswald.

For the first part of this question, apple mail supports web fonts. This is the reason you see it render properly across all apple mail clients.

For the second part (Gmail) would have Oswald in its family font, that is the only reason that I can think off that will render Oswald in your emails.

> I've tried to figure out, why 'Merriweather Sans' is not rendered
>   correctly, but no chance.

Gmail still has an issue with web fonts linked to emails and that is the reason 'Merriweather Sans' is not rendered.

Comment: Gmail is rendering Owsald only on desktop version

Comment: The desktop version has Oswald in it's stylesheet that is getting served and the app doesn't have it in it's stylesheet I guess.

Comment: You mean, I must include specific stylesheet to target gmail mobile app?
and is there a way to find fonts/safe fonts, that are similar to 'Merriweather Sans'?

Comment: Gmail app reads media queries like others do (Android and iOS). As for including fonts, webfonts will only work if it is in the styleshert served by Gmail. For websafe fonts I will update my post to add them a little later. Use inspect to see what fonts you can use thst gmail serves. i know `Roboto` works on both mobile and desktop.

Answer (score 13):

Gmail does not work with Google Fonts or any webfont.

Gmail supports a number of web safe fonts. I can't locate the list and don't see Oswald listed. Perhaps it's supported, but not listed. Or perhaps it maps to a similar font.

**Updated**

These are the fonts supported by Gmail:

• https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/g35nchmL/

```
Stackoverflow wants me to post code before I could post the link
of fonts that work in Gmail I maintain on JSFiddle.
I felt a list of fonts might be useful in choosing a fallback font.

I am not being lazy, look at the link and you'll understand.
```

For more information on fonts in email, check out the article below.

- https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the list. Is there any official documentation about the list you wrote?

Comment: @WoLfPwNeR I have never been able to locate a page by Google to list all of the fonts, so I did it myself. https://jsfiddle.net/wallyglenn/g35nchmL/. I need to update this answer to include it. The problem is that Roboto will not display correctly outside Gmail without a link to the Google fonts url.

Comment: Not sure if something has changed, but sadly Helvetica doesn't seem to work anymore. When I try to use it, gmail is swapping in Arial (confirmed with the Fonts tab in firefox's inspector). Others like Verdana still work.

Answer (score 2):

Web fonts don't have universal support, here are the email clients where they are supported:

- AOL Mail
- Native Android mail app (not Gmail app)
- Apple Mail
- iOS Mail
- Outlook 2000
- Outlook.com app

Comment: I know und understand, that not all the clients support custom Fonts, but I'm wondering why only Oswald font rendered correctly, and the other not.

Comment: Because it is installed on your OS, but normally Oswald font will not render too.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-web-fonts) on Litmus;

> Pro Tip: In April 2018,Gmail released an updated interface for their
>   webmail client. This new interface uses two popular web fonts: Google
>   Sans and Roboto. What does this mean? Despite Gmail not supporting web
>   fonts, if you use either of these web fonts in your emails, they will
>   actually render in Gmail. Simply add the fonts to your font-family CSS
>   attribute if you want to use them in your email.

Which is why there is a comment on one of the answers about Roboto working on Gmail.